# Why these parameters applied?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Applying class="container" to div causes a problem with width of div. The index takes properties from _grid.cscc.

It should be 100% width.

[image]

[image]

And it's applied on every container I make

Comment: Don't use containers for wrapping everything, just once around the whole page content - also make it container-fluid

Comment: It seems that the container is a fluid container below 1140px. From 1140px upwards the container has a fixed width of 1140px. It is not a problem to use containers in you design if you do know about the width/margin/padding in the Bootstrap grid.

Answer (score 1):

to obtain 100% width use `class="container-fluid"` instead of `container`

Answer (score 0):

Use container-fluid

.container has a max width pixel value, whereas .container-fluid is max-width 100%.

.container-fluid continuously resizes as you change the width of your window/browser by any amount.

.container resizes in chunks at several certain widths, controlled by media queries (technically we can say it’s “fixed width” because pixels values are specified, but if you stop there, people may get the impression that it can’t change size – i.e. not responsive.)